# Is there a better way than mine? Add class if elements have same attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class to elements with a specific attribute.

I tried several functions like `find()` or `filter()` but I can't get it right.

Could anybody show me a better way?

```js
$(".b").click(function() {
  $(".b").removeClass("active-filter");
  $(this).addClass("active-filter");
 
  var b = $(this).attr("data-filter");
  var active_element = $('.d[data-filter="' + b + '"]');

  $(".d").removeClass("active-element");
  active_element.addClass("active-element");
});
```

```css
.b {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
}

.c {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
}

.element {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.active-filter {
  background-color: pink;
}

.active-element {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    <div class="b active-filter" data-filter="3">data-filter</div>
    <div class="b" data-filter="4">data-filter</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="c d" data-filter="3">data-element</div>
    <div class="c d" data-filter="4">data-element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `a`? do you really need a loop?

Comment: I think you are in the wrong place. It will better if you ask in the Code Review section https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're right. I will post it there.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210811/add-class-if-element-has-same-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a more functional kinda approach? As you can see, the approach I've used, there's just a function that breaks down the problem quite nicely, at least in my opinion, rather than have one larger function, I often prefer having multiple smaller functions over one larger function, even if it takes up more space or whatever.

As you can see, once the elements have been clicked, the relevant element goes to the `process` function, from there it'll just fire the `removeClasses` function which I don't think I need to clarify it's purpose. Then it'll fire `addClasses` and add the relevant class(es) to the relevant element(s), that's it.

#### Edit

One bonus point from the perspective of efficiency is that this solution does not make use of jQuery, and it's just a fact, before anyone jumps on that bandwagon, jQuery is slower than using native implementations, but to be fair, the main **focus** of jQuery isn't performance, but rather compatibility & reliability. I doubt the difference would be so big that you'd see any major difference, i.e. users complaining about the speed(s), but just thought I'd throw this point out there too.

```js
// Short hand... 
const $e = queryString => {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll(queryString);
  if(els.length == 1) return els[0];
  else return els;
};

// A function to remove all 'active-filter' & 'active-element'. 
const removeClasses = () => {
  $e(".b").forEach(i => i.classList.remove("active-filter"));
  $e(".d").forEach(d => d.classList.remove("active-element"));
};

// A function to add 'active-filter' & 'active-element' to the relevant elements.
const addClasses = a => b => {  
  a.classList.add("active-filter");
  b.classList.add("active-element");
};

// A function to do something when relevant elements have been clicked
const process = a => {
  removeClasses();
  addClasses(a)($e(`.d[data-filter='${a.getAttribute("data-filter")}']`));
};

// Now just start the process off. 
$e(".b").forEach(b => b.onclick = () => process(b));
```

```css
.b {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
}

.c {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
}

.element {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.active-filter {
  background-color: pink;
}

.active-element {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div>
    <div class="b active-filter" data-filter="3">data-filter</div>
    <div class="b" data-filter="4">data-filter</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="c d" data-filter="3">data-element</div>
    <div class="c d" data-filter="4">data-element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why do you use `for` loop. Try this one?

```
$(".b").click(function() {
  $(".b").removeClass("active-filter");
  $(".d").removeClass('active-element');

  var clickedItem = $(this); 

  clickedItem.addClass("active-filter");
  $('.d[data-filter=' + clickedItem.data('filter') + ']').addClass('active-element');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4L91jghs/

Comment: Hi, you're right. I don't need it.

In your Version your using **clickedItem.data('filter')** 
What is happening there?

Comment: @E.G That calls the HTML5 data-* attribute. data('filter') calls data-filter value on html.

Answer (score 0):

Get the data attribute value from $(this) and find the element with the corresponding element and add class.

```js
$(".b").click(function() {
  $(".b").removeClass("active-filter");
  $(this).addClass("active-filter");
  var dataFilter = ($(this).attr("data-filter"));

    $(".d").removeClass("active-element");
    $(".element").find(".d[data-filter='" + dataFilter + "']").addClass("active-element");
});
```

```css
.b {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
}

.c {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  float: left;
}

.element {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.active-filter {
  background-color: pink;
}

.active-element {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
  <div>
    <div class="b active-filter" data-filter="3">data-filter</div>
    <div class="b" data-filter="4">data-filter</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="c d" data-filter="3">data-element</div>
    <div class="c d" data-filter="4">data-element</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did it cool. try this one out where you dont need to use any loop or any thing else.

```
$(document).on("click",".b",function() {
  $(".b").removeClass("active-filter");
  $(this).addClass("active-filter");

  $(".d").removeClass("active-element");

  var dataFilterVal = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $('.d[data-filter="' + dataFilterVal + '"]').addClass("active-element");

});
```

magic of jQuery